# Basic looping on PHP for web design

Tags: php, mysql

I am very much a newbie in PHP. Could you tell me about basic looping in PHP if I want create a web design. Also, how do I connect to a MySQL database?

Comment: Unfortunately questions related to programming are [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. You could ask this question over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but it would likely be considered too broad and incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**LOOPING**

There are two methods to loop in PHP: 
`for`, and;
`foreach`

#### The PHP for Loop

The for loop is used when you know in advance how many times the script should run.

**Syntax**

```
for (init counter; test counter; increment counter) {
    code to be executed;
}
```

*Parameters*:

init counter: Initialize the loop counter value
test counter: Evaluated for each loop iteration. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues. If it evaluates to FALSE, the loop ends.
increment counter: Increases the loop counter value
The example below displays the numbers from 0 to 10:

**Example**

```
<?php 
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
} 
?>
```

#### The PHP foreach Loop

The foreach loop works only on arrays, and is used to loop through each key/value pair in an array.

**Syntax**

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    code to be executed;
}
```

For every loop iteration, the value of the current array element is assigned to $value and the array pointer is moved by one, until it reaches the last array element.

The following example demonstrates a loop that will output the values of the given array ($colors):

**Example**

```
<?php 
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

Source: [PHP 5 for Loops](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

---

**SQL CONNECTION**

**Open a Connection to MySQL**

Before we can access data in the MySQL database, we need to be able to connect to the server:

**Example (MySQLi Object-Oriented)**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

A note on the object-oriented example above: `$connect_error` was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. If you need to ensure compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0, use the following code instead:

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**Example (MySQLi Procedural)**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

**Close the Connection**

The connection will be closed automatically when the script ends. To close the connection before, use the following:

**Example (MySQLi Object-Oriented)**

```
$conn->close();
```

**Example (MySQLi Procedural)**

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Source: [PHP Connect to MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: Thanks that help me. But how to connect the sql and database on php script could you tell me

Comment: Added SQL connection code and examples

Comment: Excellent answer! Unfortunately, the question is off-topic here.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise that it was off topic. Thanks for complimenting me on my answer though. :-)